# Equivalence of Definitions of Prime Ideal in Ring without $1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, rngs

> Let $R$ be a rng, so that $1\not\in R$. I am trying to show that following are equivalence of definition of prime ideal $P$;
>
> (i) $AB\subseteq P$ with $A,B\subseteq R$ implies $A\subseteq P$ or $B\subseteq P$
>
> (ii) $aRb\subseteq P$ with $a,b\in R$ implies that $a\in P$ or $b\in P$

I can show (ii) implies (i) by saying suppose that $AB\subseteq P$ with $A\not\subseteq P$ and $B\not \subseteq P$ then  $ARB\subseteq P$ and then fixing the elements of $A$ and $B$ in turn and applying (ii) gives the result.

I can't seem to show (i) implies (ii) though. If $R$ has a $1$ this is simple but without it I am unsure how to proceed as the ideal generated by an element is not equal to $aR$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From (i) we know that if $(a)$ and $(b)$ are principal ideals in $R$ such that $(a)(b)\subseteq P$ then we have $(a)\subseteq P$ or $(b)\subseteq P$ which implies that $a\in P$ or $b\in P$. This is also true for the product of any finite number of principal ideals. Indeed if $(a_1)(a_2)...(a_n)\subseteq P$, then at least one of them is the subset of $P$, of course if we have (i).

Now assume that (i) is true and suppose that $aRb\subseteq P$. Then $$RaRRbR\subseteq RaRbR\subseteq RPR\subseteq P.$$ 
Since $RaR$ and $RbR$ are ideals of $R$, (i) implies that $RaR\subseteq P$ or $RbR\subseteq P$. Now suppose that $RaR\subseteq P$, then
$$(a)^3\subseteq R(\mathbb Za+Ra+aR+RaR)R\subseteq RaR\subseteq P.$$
By (i), $(a)\subseteq P$ which implies that $a\in P$. Similarly, if $RbR\subseteq P$ it implies $b\in P$.

Comment: I'm fairly sure they are equivalent. It's on an examples sheet for a ring theory course I took too, but I haven't managed the question myself...

Comment: How do you conclude that $ab\in P$? It doesn't directly follow from $aRb\subseteq P$, even with commutativity.

Comment: @rschwieb: in response to your comment (pre-edit), the problem states: "Let $P \neq R$ be an ideal in a ring $R$. Show that the following are equivalent: 1) $AB \subseteq P$ for $A, B$ ideals of $R$ implies $A\subseteq P$ or $B \subseteq P$. 2) $KL \subseteq P$ for $K, L$ right ideals of $R$ implies $K \subseteq P$ or $L \subseteq P$. 3) $aRb \subseteq P$ implies $a \in P$ or $b \in P$. (Easy if $R$ has 1, harder but still true if not)."

Comment: @ah11950 : thanks for following up with that. It would be neat if it were true, but I've never seen it proven. The approach by contrapositive seems most straightforward, but it seems to run into a brick wall because $aRb\subseteq P$ does not seem to force $\Bbb Z ab\subseteq P$, which would be necessary for $(a)(b)\subseteq P$.

Comment: @ah11950 I believe we are/have taking/taken the same course!

Comment: @hmmmm Is this course material online, by chance?

Comment: @rschwieb No sorry the question is not online, I shall email my lecturer and hope that he gets back to me.

Comment: Unfortunately not...the lecturer isn't particularly au-fait with technology it seems. @hmmmm: university beginning with a 'W'?

Comment: @ah11950 It does indeed!

Comment: How did you conclude that $(a)^2(b)^3\subseteq RaRbR$?

Comment: That is if $1\notin R$ then surely we do not need to have $a\in aR$ or $b\in bR$?

Comment: I think s/he may have found a trick that works. Using $(a)(a)(b)(b)(b)$ seems to allow enough flexibility with the associative rule to fit all possible products into $RaRbR$.

Comment: @rschwieb Cool, could you possibly explain the set where we assume that $(a)^2(b)^3\subset RaRbR$? I can't see why this follows? Thanks

Comment: @hmmmm A principal ideal $(a)$ is generated by things of the form $\Bbb Za$, $aR$, $Ra$ and $\sum r_ias_i$ for $r_i,s_i\in R$. If you do the same with $(b)$ and then consider what the products of generators from $(a)(a)(b)(b)(b)$ look like, then it looks like you can always creatively group the terms so that they all fall in $RaRbR$. By distributivity, what works for the generators works for the entire product $(a)(a)(b)(b)(b)$. I could have overlooked something, but it seems to work.

Comment: @rschwieb Right ok, I'll have a play around with that to check that I get everything. Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: Sorry, I thought the bounty was awarded automatically when I accepted an answer, I have awarded it now. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @hmmmm You're welcome.