# equivalent definitions of prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $R$ be a ring (with identity) and $P\neq R$ be a (two-sided) prime ideal. Show that the following are equivalent:

1. For all $a,b \in R, ab \in P\Rightarrow a\in P$ or $b \in P.$
2. For any two elements $a,b $ of $R$, if $aRb\subseteq P,$ then $a\in P$ or $b \in P.$

Suppose $(1)$ holds and $a,b \in R$. If $aRb\subseteq P,$ then $ab \in P\Rightarrow a\in P$ or $b\in P$ by $(1).$ So $(1)\Rightarrow (2).$ Now suppose $(2)$ holds. Let $a,b \in R, ab \in P.$ Suppose $a,b\not \in P.$ We claim that $aRb\subseteq P.$ Let $axb\in aRb$ with $x\in R.$ Suppose $axb\not\in P.$ Then as $P$ is an ideal, we must have $ax\not\in P$ and $xb\not\in P.$ Then $x\not\in P.$ But I'm not sure how to get a contradiction from this.

> How does one define $(a)$ and $(b),$ the ideals generated by $a$ and $b$ for elements $a,b $ of a noncommutative ring $R$? Can one define them as left-sided ideals like $Ra$ and $Rb$? Under what circumstances can one define them as two-sided ideals like $RaR$ and $RbR$?

Comment: Generally the left/right/two side generated ideal of a point $a$, (or mor generally as set $A$) is defined to be the smallest two left/right/two-sided ideal containing $a$ (or more  generally A). This can be proved to exists via a short set-theoretic argument (which I can give as you like but I recon it is already on the site somewhere.)

Comment: Okay, so on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal) under "Prime ideals for noncommutative rings," can you explain what (a) and (b) mean? They may be left, right, or two-sided ideals, right?

Comment: Also, @user2628206, if you know how to prove the equivalence, could you provide some details? That would be more useful then proving that generated ideals exist (I know that $(a)$ is just the intersection of all ideals containing $a$)

Comment: The page keeps it ambiguous as far as I can tell (it may reasonably take $(a)\$ to be the generated left, right or two-sided ideal. Due to the other equivalent conditions mentioned in the bullet post the exact distinction does not matter as the result will hold in either way.

Comment: Sure, I have dealt with this result a while back in a rings course. Let me just check to see if there isn't already an answer on the site and also remind myself of the result.

Comment: I have found an exceedingly elegant proof for the not-necessarily unital case here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/757716/438103 .  Being for a slightly more general case than yours, the proof has a little more indirection that strictly required but is still given in an economical fashion. Additionally, the  result proved is slightly different from the result that you require (as proves a result for general ideals not just principally generated), but I would wager that this answer gives the details you need. If not comment to let myself and others know. Best

Comment: @user2628206 thanks, but I think it's easier to prove the result if you assume the ring has an identity. Also, why are $RaR$ and $RbR$ both ideals? I'm not sure how to show they're abelian subgroups under $+$. And why is it true that $(a)^3 \subseteq R(\mathbb{Z}a + Ra + aR + RaR)R$?

Comment: Finally, does $\mathbb{Z} a$ mean $\{k a : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$?

Comment: Yep!, $\mathbb Za = \{k a : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128864/discussion-between-user2628206-and-alfred).

Answer (score 4):

For noncommutative rings, the statements are not equivalent. For example, let $R$ be 2x2 matrices over a field, and $P=0$. Then $P$ satisfies (2) but not (1). That is, given matrices $a,b$, if $aRb=0$, then either $a=0$ or $b=0$, so (2) holds. However, if $a=E_{12}$, the elementary matrix having a one in the top right corner and zeros elsewhere, then $a^2=0$, but $a\neq0$, so (1) fails.

Primes satisfying (1) are usually called completely prime ideals.

Comment: On the Wikipedia page, $(a)$ means the smallest two-sided ideal containing $a$. It’s elements are finite sums of things of the form $xay$ with $x,y\in R$.